# How to make ListBox remove a CollectionChanged event handler from its ItemsSource

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Having a `ListBox`, a

```
listBox.ItemsSource = myObservableCollection;
```

will add an event handler to `myObservableCollection.CollectionChanged`.

But

```
listBox.ItemsSource = null;
```

or

```
listBox.ItemsSource = anotherObservableCollection;
```

won’t remove the event handler from `myObservableCollection.CollectionChanged`.

How can I make the `ListBox` remove its event handler from that event?

That the event handler actually isn’t removed can be seen e.g. when using something like this:

```
class MyObservableCollection<T> : ObservableCollection<T>
{
    public override event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler? CollectionChanged
    {
        add { Trace.WriteLine("add"); base.CollectionChanged += value; }
        remove { Trace.WriteLine("remove"); base.CollectionChanged -= value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: The CollectionChanged event is handled by the binding engine that subscribes to the CollectionChanged using a weak event manager. The binding engine will manage the lifetime of the subscription and the stored reference to the associated CollectionView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I make the ListBox remove its event handler from that event?

Use the `DetachFromSourceCollection` method of the `CollectionView`:

```
CollectionView view = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(listBox.ItemsSource)
    as CollectionView;
view?.DetachFromSourceCollection();
listBox.ItemsSource = null;
```